# Jquery/ajax: autocomplete with ajax from a substring in textbox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this `txt_Remarks` textbox in `asp.net`, what I have done is used ajaxToolkitLibrary to specify a source of autocompletion list which is defined like this,

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetItemRemarks(string prefixText, int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        count = 10;
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
    SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader sdr = null;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT REMARKS FROM mstRemark WHERE BranchId='"+ Globals.BranchID +"' AND Id<>1 AND REMARKS like '%" + prefixText.Trim() + "%' ";
        sdr = ExecuteReader(cmd);
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            items.Add("" + sdr.GetValue(0));
        }
        sdr.Close();
        sdr.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception )
    {

    }
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

what I want it, after a item is select say `premium user` instead of ending auto complete, a comma be put there and new list of item is shown to user based on what he is typing right now.

say, he starts typing p== its shows premium, predefined, pattern, etc.. when he clicks premium, it gets set in text box, and then a comma be put there, and he can type again, say he again types p== it should show again premium, predefined, pattern, this time he clicks pattern, the textbox would show `preminum, pattern` and allows him to work like this until he clicks somewhere else. 
So, basically this autocomplete should work based a custom substring, I also tried using $.ajax() but no luck, I couldn't even get it to work for that matter..
So, how can this be done?

*EDIT:* **something like what happends in stackoverflow** when you enter a start typing a tag, it shows a list, when u select it, it is entered into box, and you can type again and that tag is added to the list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout the Chosen jquery plugin, it does pretty much exactly what you're describing I believe.

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Thanks man! Its exactly (more or less) what I am looking for!